# Aqua Data studio won't let me create this view

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a Postgres Database on Aqua Data Studio 6.5.12 (Yes, it is a really old system, but i like it very much :) ).

I've got a query running normally in the Query Analyzer, but when I try to save it as a view, I'm receiving "ERROR: Syntax error near SELECT".

Do someone know what could be wrong in it?

```
SELECT test_configs.sgsn, test_configs.imsi, 
    CASE test_configs.mncl 
        WHEN '' THEN '-' 
        ELSE COALESCE(test_configs.mncl, '-') 
        END AS mncl 

FROM config_imsis_sgsn AS default_configs 
    LEFT JOIN config_imsis_sgsn AS test_configs 
    ON default_configs.sgsn = f_sgsn_correto() 
    AND default_configs.imsi = test_configs.imsi 
    AND test_configs.sgsn <> default_configs.sgsn

WHERE COALESCE(default_configs.mncl, 'null') <> COALESCE(test_configs.mncl, 'null') AND test_configs.sgsn <> ''
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` statement is malformed.

Try modifying the `SELECT` to be like this:

```
SELECT test_configs.sgsn, test_configs.imsi, 
    CASE 
        WHEN test_configs.mncl = '' THEN '-' 
        ELSE COALESCE(test_configs.mncl, '-') 
    END AS mncl
```

Note that I am basing this behavior off of *Postgres* 9.3, although I don't think this particular behavior has changed in quite some time. I assume that your version of *Postgres* that *Aqua Data Studio 6* is using is quite old, as, while I'm not familiar with that product, it would appear the most recent version is 14, indicating that it's likely many years old.

Comment: The error persists... What scares me is: In the query analyzer, I can do it run normally. The excly rows I need are returned. But when saving it, it fails!

Comment: Hmm... that sounds like it may be an Aqua Data Studio bug, then, perhaps, as with the changed `CASE` statement, from a *Postgres* perspective, I would expect it to work.